# Xamarin subclassed UINavigationController with custom UINavigationBar

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a non-standard top navigation bar for use throughout my application. To achieve this I've been trying to subclass `UINavigationController` and `UINavigationBar`

I have a custom `NavigationController` class

```
partial class ZooNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public ZooNavigationController (IntPtr handle) : base (typeof(TopNavBar), null)
    {
        this.Handle = handle;
    }
}
```

which points to the base constructor

```
public UINavigationController (Type navigationBarType, Type toolbarType);
```

for my custom `UINavigationBar` class `TopNavBar` which is something like...

```
public class TopNavBar : UINavigationBar
{
    public TopNavBar ()
    {
        InitCustom ();
    }

    public void InitCustom(){ 
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red; 
        // a bunch more custom stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is, TopNavBar is never called when I run this. If I try to adjust my constructor to look like this:

```
    public ZooNavigationController (IntPtr handle) : base (typeof(TopNavBar), null)
    {
        this.Handle = handle;
        TopNavBar test = (TopNavBar)this.NavigationBar;
    }
```

I get a runtime exception that it can't cast the types, so it seems that it's ignoring my call specifying the `UINavigationBar` type.

Can anyone help me out with what I'm missing here?

**EDIT** in the end it turns out I was missing the fact that you can set a custom UINavigationBar inside the storyboard. Combining that with the miguel's answer I ended up with the class

```
partial class TopNavBar : UINavigationBar
{
    public TopNavBar(IntPtr test) : base(test) {
    }

    [Export ("initWithCoder:")]
    public TopNavBar (NSCoder coder) : base (coder)  {
        InitCustom ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IntPtr constructor is called in response to the object being created by Objective-C and surfaced to C#.   This in general is not the way that these classes are instantiated.

The first question that you have to ask yourself is: who is creating the instance of your class?

- You create the instance of this class from C#: you call a constructor with the proper parameters.
- Being created during deserialization (for example, loading from a storyboard, XIB, or your own archived data), then you need to provide the constructor that takes an NSCoder parameter.
- Having your instance recreated on demand (may indicate a problem, because it means that your object was destroyed, but Objective-C kept a reference to it, and now it is being resurfaced again), the IntPtr constructor.

In your example above, there is a mistake: you are overriding the IntPtr constructor, which should only ever call into the base class IntPtr constructor (since it means "I have a pointer to the real object in objective-c, create a wrapper for it").

My guess is that you are using C#, so in that case, what you want is to provide a new constructor that takes no arguments:

```
public ZooNavigationController () : base (typeof (YourNavigation), typeof(YourBar)) {
   // Your own initialization goes here
}
```